# Wait all tasks one by one with the same transaction instance failed c#

Tags: c#, transactions, task-parallel-library, dapper

I am using the wait all one by one approach inside one transaction instance and I get this error when calling the Commit method on the transaction instance:

[image]

What Am I missing here?

This is the code:

```
.
.
.
using Dapper;
using DapperExtensions;
.
.
.    
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                connection.Open();
                var tlis = GetTlis(connection).ToList();
                using (var trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var tasks = tlis.Take(10).Select(tli => Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        (dynamic @params) =>
                        {
                            ProcessTli(@params.Connection, @params.Transaction, tli);
                        },
                        new { Connection = connection, Transaction = trans }
                        )).ToList();

                    var tlisAmount = 0;

                    while (tasks.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //const int timeout = 3600*1000;
                        var winner = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

                        if (winner < 0)
                            break;

                        tlisAmount++;
                        tasks.RemoveAt(winner);

                        Cmd.Write("({0}%) ", tlisAmount*100/tlis.Count);

                        var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
                        Cmd.Write(timeSpan.ToString("c") + "  ");

                        Cmd.Write("Processing {0} of {1}   ", tlisAmount, tlis.Count);
                        Cmd.Write('\r');
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        trans.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Cmd.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        trans.Rollback();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

        private static void ProcessTli(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction, Tli tli)
        {
            var quotesTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetQuotesByTli(connection, transaction, tli));

            quotesTask.ContinueWith(quotes =>
            {
                quotes.Result.ToList().ForEach(quote =>
                {
                    var tliTransaction = new TliTransaction(quote);
                    connection.Insert(tliTransaction, transaction);
                });
            });

            var billOfLadingsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>GetBillOfLadings(connection, transaction, tli));

                billOfLadingsTask.ContinueWith(billOfLadings =>
                {
                    var bolGroupsByDate = from bol in billOfLadings.Result.ToList()
                        group bol by bol.Year;

                    bolGroupsByDate.ToList().ForEach(bolGroupByDate =>
                    {
                        var bol = new BillOfLading
                        {
                            As400FormatQuoteDate = bolGroupByDate.ElementAt(0).As400FormatQuoteDate,
                            CommodityCode = tli.CommodityCode,
                            TariffOcurrenciesAmount = bolGroupByDate.Count(),
                            TliNumber = tli.TliNumber
                        };
                        var tliTransaction = new TliTransaction(tli, bol);
                        connection.Insert(tliTransaction, transaction);
                    });
                });

                Task.WaitAll(quotesTask, billOfLadingsTask);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should use `Task.Run()` rather than `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: If I were you, I would try and reduce how much computation etc etc I was doing in a transaction scope. I think that a transaction scope should only be reading/writing of data - not computation etc.

Comment: I don't see how I could take some code out of that transaction scope. I am just retrieving some data from a database and inserting new rows in a table.

Comment: Then why do you have all these tasks being spawned off. and tonnes and tonnes of code? You don't need to spawn of tasks to simply project an object to another.

Comment: I have to loop through 37900 records then for each one query two different tables take both record sets then insert into another table. I don't want that unrelated methods waiting to execute needlessly. I am not sure if this is the right way of doing this. That's why I am looking for a different point of view.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't try spawning off loads and loads of tasks. I would just pull all the data you need to process, close connection, process data, open connection, write data. Do this in a method which is spawned by `Task.Run()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this (note this shows the process, not the extact code...)

```
public void ModifyData()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var tlis = GetTlis(connection).ToList();
        connection.Open();

        Quotes quotes;
        BillOfLading billOfLading;

        using (var trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            quotes = GetQuotesByTli(connection, transaction, tli);

            billOfLading = GetBillOfLadings(connection, transaction, tli);
        }
    }

    // Process those items retrieved from the database.
    var processedItems = this.Process(/* the items that you want to process */);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var tlis = GetTlis(connection).ToList();
        connection.Open();

        using (var trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // do all your inserts.
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would run it:

```
await Task.Run(() => ModifyData());
```

This [resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) shows a really good example of running multiple tasks.